# Anyone know where the Viewport Overlay options (and others) went in Blender 4.0?

Tags: interface

There used to be several useful buttons here with much customization within, I can tell that the functionality is still within Blender 4.0 as my old files have some of these options toggled on, but I can no longer find where to change them in 4.0.

Below is an image of where they would be in 4.0,

[image: Screencap from Blender 4.0]

and here is an image from 3.6 that has all those options, with the viewport overlays menu maximized:

[image: Screencap of the viewport overlays menu from 3.6]

I'm mostly interested in viewport overlays, but all of the options at the bottom right of this screenshot were options that I used daily, and I have sifted through all the available menus in 4.0 and can't seem to find them.

Comment: Are you talking about viewport shading/ eevee/ cycles etc buttons?

Comment: Hello and welcome, try to factory reset Blender (File > Defaults > Load factory settings) the options should be on the top right corner of the viewport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my 3.6 files are bugged and I had to reset Blender to factory defaults.

Edit: Also, as John suggested below, loading your old files with "Load UI" unchecked may work for some people. It did not work for me however, I had to completely factory reset then load my old keybinds. (which I have been informed will cause issues, but I don't care, I want my keybinds)

Comment: Add that to the list of reasons you should finish your projects in the Blender versions they were started with.

Comment: Alternatively you could try running Blender then loading the 'buggy' files with 'Load UI' unchecked on the File selector N panel. If that fixes it you can turn that option off permanently under Preferences > Save & Load > Blend Files.

Comment: It was a fresh file, with settings loaded from 3.6 using the splash screen option. Thanks Duarte :)